# How to calculate homotopy invariant winding number?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Consider a map $f:S^1\to U(1)=S^1$, since we know $\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$, which measures how many times the map "wind" around the circle. Given some explicit form of the function $f(\phi$), where $\phi$ is the coordinate on the circle, we can calculate the winding number by $$ \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{i}{2\pi f(\phi)}f'(\phi)d\phi$$

Given a map $f:S^2 \to S^2$ and it is known that $\pi_2(S^2)=\mathbb{Z}$. What is the quantity/formula being used to calculate the degree of the map?

In general, how does one construct the formula for calculating the winding number for arbitary $\pi_n(\mathcal{M})$ ?

Comment: You can, for example, find a volume form on $S^2$ with integral $1$, and integrate its pullback along $f$. In general homotopy groups, or for that matter homology groups, contain torsion, so there's no hope for an integral formula. For degrees you can again use volume forms.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Could you please elaborate more? I am sorry that my background is more applied math. What do you mean by the volume form on $S^2$ with integral $1$ and its pullback along $f$?

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1079004/pdf/pnas01698-0025.pdf

This is an example of the hopf mapping which is $\pi_3(S^2)$